# Brake lights do not illuminate

Tags: honda, civic, brake-light

2006 Honda Civic 2 door coupe brake lights don't work. I've checked all fuses and replaced the brake light switch and still no power to the lights. But when I engage the switch I hear a strange clicking sound under the shifter.

Comment: Clicking like a relay? Have you managed to find a wiring diagram for the car? Brake lights should be a relatively simple system, electrically..

Comment: Supposedly there is no relay system in these cars

Comment: Have you owned the car from new?

Comment: Its a friend of mines and he's had it for a while and this happened suddenly and I'm trying to fix it for him.

Comment: I just found out that he had the engine replaced recently and he is not sure when they stopped working. Im really thinking that somwthing disnt get groundwd back properly or something.

Comment: If it is an auto, the clicking noise under the shifter is likely the lock being released that allows you to move the shifter out of park.

Comment: Have you checked the brake light bulbs?

Comment: It moves out of park fine and the bulbs are fine.